# Where to put a 3rd-party API in Laravel 4

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the Google Analytics API to get some info to my app. It's a PHP class that I can instantiate and use to pull data from GA.

My first thought was to put it in a new folder (app/lib), and then autoload it from composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/lib/google/api"
    ]
}
```

I can then instantiate in my controller and use as I wish: `$ga = new Google\Api\gapi(ga_email, ga_password);`

However, since it's a data access layer for my application, I also tried putting it in a model and instantiating it that way. Both work, I'm just trying to follow some best-practices.  Or is there another place I should be putting it, like the vendor folder.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd want it to be a package under the `vendor` folder which is managed by composer. There's a number of people who have packaged up the `GAPI` library on Packagist, saving you the work of creating a location, autoloading it, keeping it updated, etc.

https://packagist.org/search/?q=gapi

Just add the requirement to your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "dandydev/gapi-php": "dev-master"
}
```

Then in the command line in that folder run

```
composer update
```